# how to install terraform on linux

Tags: linux, curl, terraform

I'm trying to install terraform on linux but getting and error

```
curl -o https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.2/terraform_0.11.2_linux_amd64.zip
```

its giving error as

```
curl: no URL specified!
```

can some one help me on this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

thanks i'm able to download by using `--remote-name` before URL

```
curl -o --remote-name https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.2/terraform_0.11.2_linux_amd64.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14.5M  100 14.5M    0     0  37.1M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 37.2M
```

Comment: You could also use something like `curl  https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.2/terraform_0.11.2_linux_amd64.zip -o tf-11.2.zip`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with the `-O` or`--remote-name` flag, `curl` writes output to a local file named like the remote file we get. So, with this command you can do it:

```
curl -O -L ttps://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.2/terraform_0.11.2_linux_amd64.zip
```

Here is the portion of the [manual pages of `curl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) that describes the `-O/--remote-name` and `--remote-name-all` flags:

> #### `-O/--remote-name`
>
> Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get. (Only the file part of the remote file is used, the path is cut off.)
>
> The remote file name to use for saving is extracted from the given URL, nothing else.
>
> You may use this option as many times as the number of URLs you have.
>
> #### `--remote-name-all`
>
> This option changes the default action for all given URLs to be dealt with as if -O/--remote-name were used for each one. So if you
>   want to disable that for a specific URL after --remote-name-all has
>   been used, you must use "-o -" or --no-remote-name. (Added in 7.19.0)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the reason this is happening is becUse you need it to follow this format
`curl https://whatever.com/whateverfile.zip -o local/output/path/whateverfile.zip`

But what you are doing is not actually specifying the remote url